# express checkout module in zencart

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I have embed this code for CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile but when i put this code in expresscheckout modulle (paypalwpp.php) then after payment return to website it show blank page can any one solve this problem here is code.

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['r'])){
  $t =   $_SESSION['paypal_ec_token'];
  $amount = $_SESSION['total_amount'];
  $frequency = $_SESSION['r'];
  $d = date('c'); 
  $token = urlencode("$t");
  $paymentAmount = urlencode($amount);
  $currencyID = urlencode("USD");
  $startDate = urlencode("$d");
  $billingPeriod = urlencode("Week");
  $billingFreq = urlencode($frequency);
$nvpStr="&TOKEN=$token&AMT=$paymentAmount&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID&PROFILESTARTDATE=$startDate";
$nvpStr .= "&BILLINGPERIOD=$billingPeriod&BILLINGFREQUENCY=$billingFreq";
$nvpStr .= "&DESC=Recurring Payment";
$httpParsedResponseAr = self::PPHttpPost('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile', $nvpStr);

 if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" ==        strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
$profile_id = $httpParsedResponseAr['PROFILEID'];
$profile_id  = str_replace("%2d","-",$profile_id);
   $q = mysql_query("insert into recurring_profiles(profile_id) values('$profile_id')") or die(mysql_error());
 $recu_id = mysql_insert_id();
if($q){
    unset($_SESSION['total_amount']);
    $_SESSION['s'] = true;
    $_SESSION['recu_id'] = $recu_id;
}
else{
    echo "<h1>Sorry PROFILEID ERROR";
}

        //exit('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile Completed Successfully:  '.print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
    }    
    else  {
//echo "<br/><h1>Problem Occurs please shop again sorry for this inconvinence<br/>";
//exit('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr,  true));

   }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with some default good values, and the mechanism works. Obviously, if you have a blank page, there is a failure in one of the conditions, or an error on one of the queries.

You should allow the comments and add more debugs.

```
 $httpParsedResponseAr = self::PPHttpPost('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile', $nvpStr);

 /* check this when it comes from paypal or not. */
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
 echo "</pre>";

 if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) 
     || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
     $profile_id = $httpParsedResponseAr['PROFILEID'];
     $profile_id  = str_replace("%2d","-",$profile_id);

     /* this query might be broke. Mabye there is no table to insert into. 
      * I mean, is this recurring_profiles a function work inside the quotes?

     $q = mysql_query("insert into recurring_profiles(profile_id) 
                       values('$profile_id')") or die(mysql_error());

      */

     /* maybe this is better. There is a space at the table name and the
      * (column). and you can bug check the query if if fails. */

     $query = "insert into recurring_profiles (profile_id) 
                       values('$profile_id')";
     $q = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>Query: $query<br>");

     $recu_id = mysql_insert_id();
     if($q){
         unset($_SESSION['total_amount']);
         $_SESSION['s'] = true;
         $_SESSION['recu_id'] = $recu_id;
     }
     else{
         echo "<h1>Sorry PROFILEID ERROR";
     }

     exit('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile Completed Successfully:'
          .print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
    }    
 else  {
    echo "<br/><h1>Problem Occurs</h1> Please shop again sorry for this inconvinence<br/>";
    exit('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile failed: ' 
          . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr,  true));
  }
```